# How do I have row number on a conditional result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to give row numbers as rankings to my result set from the SQL statement. I followed up the doc but the `ROW` function which should have `OVER` is causing trouble and inefficiency.

Without any row numbering, this is the query:

```
select 
    count(*) number_of_people, p.address_state state_code, a.us_state_terr state_name
from 
    person_economic_info p 
inner join
    annotated_person_info a on p.address_state = a.numeric_id
group by 
    p.address_state, a.us_state_terr
order by 
    number_of_people desc
```

I could not understand as to how, without using `count(*)` twice in my SQL queries, can I get my results ranking.

I tried using the following SQL query. It was both wrong and inefficient IMO:

```
select 
    count(*) number_of_people, p.address_state state_code, a.us_state_terr state_name,
    row_number over (order by number_of_people desc) as Rank
from 
    person_economic_info p 
inner join
    annotated_person_info a on p.address_state = a.numeric_id 
group by 
    p.address_state, a.us_state_terr
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server 16b9151564e7, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.

I expect to write a statement which can rank my result and have a column for "Rank" as well.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()`, not `ROW_NUMBER`, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to the column-alias *number_of_people* at the same level. Use `count(*)` instead in your `row_number` function and it should work as expected.

```
select count(*) number_of_people
      , p.address_state state_code
      , a.us_state_terr state_name
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by count(*) desc) AS [Rank] 
from person_economic_info p 
inner join annotated_person_info a on p.address_state = a.numeric_id 
group by p.address_state, a.us_state_terr
```

Comment: Won't that call the `count()` twice?

Comment: you can look at the *query execution plan* to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using the count(*) twice you can first create a CTE and use it to create the rank:

```
with cte as (
select count(*) number_of_people
      , p.address_state state_code
      , a.us_state_terr state_name 
from person_economic_info p 
    inner join annotated_person_info a on p.address_state = a.numeric_id 
group by p.address_state, a.us_state_terr
)
select   c.state_code
        ,c.state_name
        ,c.number_of_people
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by c.number_of_people desc) AS [Rank] 
from cte as c
```